# How can I install Ruby 1.9.3 in Mac OS X Mountain Lion without Xcode?

Tags: ruby, osx-mountain-lion

I would like to know about alternative ways to build a development machine for Ruby 1.9.3 on OS X 10.8 Mountain Lion, that does not require Xcode.

Mountain Lion is now Golden Master as I'm writing this question, so it could be considered as final version. That cannot be said about Xcode, that is a preview release yet.

RVM recommends to install osx-gcc-installer over Xcode, but I would like not to mess my system.

What is the cleanest way to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mountain Lion without Xcode?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

osx-gcc-installer turns out to be a very good option to replace Xcode in order to install Ruby 1.9.3

These are the steps I have followed:

1. Download & install the latest version of osx-gcc-installer here (GCC-10.7-v2 is fine): https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer
2. Install RVM as usual and select 1.9.3-head as the default ruby installation: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/
3. Install Homebrew: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation
4. Install libksba to resolve some dependencies with Ruby 1.9.3: `brew install libksba`

**That's it!** You should now have Ruby 1.9.3 installed on Mountain Lion working perfectly.

If you need some other packages, install them now through Homebrew, such as Imagemagick for example: `brew install imagemagick`

It's possible that you need XQuartz for Homebrew to work properly, as Apple is not shipping X11 since Mountain Lion. You can download it here: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki

**EDIT:**

Now (since 29th July) Command line tools for Xcode 4.4 are available.

So, the new steps are these:

1. Download & install Command line tools for Xcode 4.4 (you don't need to download Xcode): https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action
2. Install Homebrew: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/installation
3. Install automake: `brew install automake`
4. Install RVM as usual and select 1.9.3-head as the default ruby installation: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Optional step: You may need XQuartz for some components, for example for Imagemagick, so download & install XQuartz: http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki

Comment: I needed XQuartz too for fink and MacPorts (well, not "need" but it was checked in the configs). XQuartz seems to work fine under Mountain Lion.

Comment: @holyredbeard `brew install automake` installed fine for me on Mountain Lion.

Comment: The rvm.io website is hideous. For step 4, I followed the instructions here: http://octopress.org/docs/setup/rvm/ and then after that, I also installed rails using `gem install rails --version '~> 3.2.0'`

Answer (score 1):

I also had to add this:

export CC=/usr/bin/gcc-4.2

in order to make the Apple command line tools work with the rvm.  Without this I had repeated llvm issues:

The provided CC(gcc) is LLVM based, it is not yet fully supported by ruby and gems, please read `rvm requirements`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add

```
export CPPFLAGS=-I/opt/X11/include
```

as well as

```
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.2
```

I was still getting compilation errors due to readline (things like `readline.c: In function ‘readline_s_vi_editing_mode_p’:` in the make.log file), and the [RVM readline page](https://rvm.io/packages/readline/) didn't seem to help, so I ran

```
brew install readline
```

followed by

```
rvm install 1.9.3 -C --with-readline-dir=/usr/local/Cellar/readline/6.2.4
```