# Error installing Ruby 1.9.3 on OS X 10.8.1

Tags: ruby

I am trying to upgrade Ruby with rvm. I am getting this error. First post.

```
macbook:bin stephentrovato$ rvm install 1.9.3
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3, this may         take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3 - #fetching 
ERROR: Error running 'bunzip2 '/Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.9.3-.tar.bz2'', please read /Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3/extract.log
ruby-1.9.3 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3- to /Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3
ERROR: Error running 'tar xf /Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.9.3-.tar -C /Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_1714', please read /Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3/extract.log
ERROR: There has been an error while trying to extract the source.  
Halting the installation.
ERROR: There has been an error fetching the ruby interpreter. Halting the installation.
```

Edit:  Error log - 
[2012-12-02 17:52:35] tar xf /Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.9.3-.tar -C /Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_2516
tar: Error opening archive: Failed to open '/Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/archives/ruby-1.9.3-.tar'

Comment: Did you read `/Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3/extract.log`?

Comment: do you have xcode on your mac?

Comment: Do you have xcode or command line tools installed?

Comment: or try this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436674/how-can-i-install-ruby-1-9-3-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-without-xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436674/how-can-i-install-ruby-1-9-3-in-mac-os-x-mountain-lion-without-xcode)
if you don't want to use full xcode

Comment: I do have xcode, maybe it's not installed properly?

Comment: Feel like a n00b, I can't find /Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3/extract.log

Comment: it's in an invisible folder, can't see it in the Finder. In Terminal, try `open -e /Users/stephentrovato/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3/extract.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something weird happening with RVM, it's not choosing the patchlevel correctly. There's lots of references to `ruby-1.9.3-` which should be `ruby-1.9.3-p327`. I think that's why it can't fetch the archive, should be nothing to do with Xcode.

Try updating your RVM by doing `rvm get stable` and then try again.

Comment: Thank you. I did have to run `rvm get head` but after the update i installed 1.9.3 no problem.