# RVM installation without XCode issue

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, osx-mavericks

I've been following this answer, except I'm on OSX Mavericks: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11436675.

I've downloaded the current version of Command Line Tools (I've also installed osx-gcc-installer as well, I don't know if that matters or not).

When I run: `pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables`, I get:

```
 ...
 version: 5.1.0.0.1.1396320587
 ...
```

so I definitely have Command Line Tools installed. I'm trying to install RVM so I ran this command: `rvm install ruby-2.0.0` and got the following:

```
Xcode version older than 4.6.2 installed, download and install newer version from:

http://connect.apple.com

After installation open Xcode, go to Downloads and install Command Line Tools.\n'

Xcode version older than 4.6.2 installed, download and install newer version from:

http://connect.apple.com

After installation open Xcode, go to Downloads and install Command Line Tools.

++ return 1
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At your link it says:

> 2) Install RVM as usual...

And this:

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```

is not how you install rvm.  To install rvm, go to the rvm website:

https://rvm.io/

Then scroll down to the bottom of the page and under the RVM heading, click on Installation.  Then read about how to install rvm for your setup, which probably is this:

> 1) Download and run the RVM installation script
>
> Installing the stable release version:

```
user$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

To execute that command, open up a Terminal window (Applications/Utilities/Terminal), and cd to your Home directory:

$ cd /Users/

(Your Home directory is represented by a ~ in the prompt.)

You can also cd to your home directory, doing this:

```
$ cd ~
```

or just:

```
$ cd
```

Then copy and paste this:

```
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

to the right of your prompt, then hit return.  That will install rvm.

To have rvm install ruby for you, click the link to the rvm website, scroll down to the bottom of the page, and under the heading Rubies, click on Installing Rubies.